# why opensuse install ruby 2.1 while installing 2.4

Tags: ruby, installation, opensuse

Opensuse Leap 42.2
trying to install ruby-2.4

```
zypper in ruby2.4
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following 4 NEW packages are going to be installed:
ruby2.1 ruby2.1-rubygem-gem2rpm ruby2.4 ruby-common

The following recommended package was automatically selected:
ruby2.1-rubygem-gem2rpm

4 new packages to install.
Overall download size: 521.0 KiB. Already cached: 0 B. After the 
operation, additional 1.5 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/...? shows all options] (y):
```

Why system wants to install an old version with a new one?